# DataView containers can’t have more than one column

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I created a Dataview in wxWidgets but it seems that if I add children to an item then only one column shows on the item

[image: without children]

[image]

I created a Dataview and added an item to it and another item
The Dataview has 3 columns but only one of the non containers (items with no children) had all 3 columns

Comment: @oqamn, please check the `dataview` sample. Build and run it, then look at the code.

Answer (score 0):

To show values in the other container item columns you need to override [HasContainerColumns() in your model](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.2/classwx_data_view_model.html#a1c8983afee8875226c2b11500f228ae4) class to return `true`.